# What exactly is the initialization of character arrays with string literals in C++?

Tags: c++

As I write `char str[] = "1"`, is it `char str[] = {'1', '\0'}`, or `char str[] = {"1"[0], "1"[1]}`?

Though, for the compiler's point of view, these two are interchangeable since `"1"` is `const char[2]`. How is it defined? Or rather, what exactly does 'characters of the value of the string literal' mean in a C++ context?

---

What I was thinking was like, if it were 'elements of the string literal' it should be the second one. But the wording in the standard seems to have made it ambiguous.

Or maybe: Which one is original intent of the standard? Or does it just explicitly not care about it, as the behavior of the implementation is not affected?

Comment: C uses zero terminated strings so I guess the answer to your question is "yes", i.e. as you said it doesn't matter. So as a definition, I think you would be obliged to define it as {'1', '\0'}. I don't think your second suggestion would have any meaning. And I'm not sure what you meant by `char[4]`, this would be more like `char[2]`, no?

Comment: @EmilVatai I mistyped  :/

Comment: Which standard (C11, C++11, ...) do you implicitly refer to?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch C++17，and I think I should forget about C...

Comment: Then remove the mention of C in the title.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch already did so :|

Comment: The C++ standard describes behaviour of an implementation, not its internal workings.

Comment: @n.m. True, the behavior of implementation is not affected. But why `characters of the value of the string literal` instead `characters of the string literal` or `elements of the string literal` which are more clear. That's what I wonder.

Comment: Characters that make up this string literal `"\n\x42"` are very different from characters that make up its value. Strictly speaking they do not even need to be from the same character set.

Comment: @n.m. I think I get what you meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>(your initial title mentioned both C & C++; they are different languages)</sup>

A [literal string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) such as `"1"` is *defined* to mean an array of `char`-s ending with the <kbd>NUL</kbd> byte, so `char str[] = "1";` is exactly like `char str[] = {'1', '\0'}` and the literal `"1"` is behaving *exactly* as some anonymous array like `char anonymous_str[]={'1',0};`. The compiler is allowed (but not required) to compile `"ab"` and `"b"` in such way that `"ab"+1 == "b"` in the pointer equality sense.

A more subtle question is the `const`-ness of string elements, etc... This is slightly different in C and in C++. In C, for historical reasons, a literal string has non-`const` elements of type `char` which are not allowed to be changed. So `"abc"[1] = '.';` is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in C (where the type of `"abc"` is `(char*)` or more exactly `char[4]`), but IIRC is forbidden (ill-typed) in C++ (where the type of `"abc"` is `(const char*)` or more exactly `const char[4]`).

And any good [optimizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) C++ compiler would handle `char str[] = {"1"[0], "1"[1]}` *exactly* like `char str[] = {'1', '\0'}` or `char str[] = "1"` (per the [as-if rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule)).

For [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)), read its [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) standard and its [§6.4.5 string literals](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5).

For [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), read its [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) standard and its §2.14.5 string literals. For later versions of C++, find and refer to their standard documentation.

PS. Officially, n1570 & n3337 are drafts. In practice, they are the standards (but the official document has to be bought).

Comment: `Successive characters of the value of the string literal initialize the elements of the array. ` The wording seems to have not been changed since n3337.